# TIdHTTPServer altering HTML

Tags: html, delphi, formatting, indy, httpserver

I'm using the `TIdHTTPServer` to host a large set of existing HTML files. However, I have a problem where it's returning altered HTML. Mainly, double quotes (`“`) are being replaced with jibberish like `â€œ`. Viewing the HTML file directly from my filesystem in Edge shows just fine, but the same page / file when served through this Indy HTTP server gets altered.

I'm returning the file via a `TFileStream` like so:

```
    FS:= TFileStream.Create(FN, fmOpenRead);
    AResponseInfo.ContentStream:= FS;

    FE:= LowerCase(ExtractFileExt(FN));
    if FMime.IndexOfName(FE) >= 0 then
      CT:= FMime.Values[FE]
    else
      CT:= 'application/octet-stream';

    AResponseInfo.ContentType:= CT; //text/html in this case
```

The raw HTML file has this:

```
<p>“<strong>Y</strong>” = Consigned</p>
```

...which looks like this:

[image: Correct formatting]

But when served through Indy, the HTML has this:

```
<p>â€œ<strong>Y</strong>â€ = Consigned</p>
```

...which looks like this:

[image: Incorrect formatting]

What is going wrong, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just figured it out - I need to set the character set:

```
AResponseInfo.CharSet := 'utf-8';
```